# Logging For Update Check In Install4J Launcher

Tags: install4j

Is there a way to capture the output of a version check?  One of my installers isn't tripping the update and I can't tell if it's a bad update URL or a problem with the .xml.  My other installers have auto-update working correctly.

Thanks,
Carl

Comment: I didn't see anything about the update check in the i4j log file.  This applies to the successful updaters too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of 8.0.5, there is no user-configurable logging for auto-update checks and launcher integrations, I've created an issue for it.

The only workaround at this time is to do the check programmatically with the code snippet that is given by the integration wizard on the "Launcher integration" tab of the updater application. Then you can add logging output yourself.

Comment: Thank you. I did see an auto-update error in the i4j log file when I shutdown the web server.  I have a feeling that the version is a problem though it seems to conform to what the docs permit.

Comment: I've added the ApplicationLauncher code from the wizard.  Is there a snippet that I could added to tap into the auto-update check?

Comment: getUpdateDescriptor() returns the correct possibleUpdateEntry.  Is there something else I should look for in my Install4J project to figure out why the prompt isn't being displayed automatically?

Comment: Thank you for including this in the next release. Making some install4j library calls verified that the auto-updater was doing its job.  My particular issue was that a Set Variable on updateDescriptorEntry step was missing from my Update Downloader Action.